# Commutative Ring with p elements and the identity is a domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let p be a prime. Prove that every commutative ring with the identity and p elements is a domain.

Any help or hints on how to get started would be great thanks

Thanks for any help

Comment: The commutativity assumption is not needed.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043373

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Lagrange, the order of the subgroup$\rm\: G = \{r:rs=0\}\:$ divides $\rm\:|(A,+)| = p\:$
prime.

Thus $\rm\:|G| = p\ (\Rightarrow 1\cdot s = 0)\:$ or $\rm\:|G| = 1\ (\Rightarrow\ rs\ne 0\ \ if\ \ r,s\ne0)$.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT** If the ring has $p$ elements, then its additive structure must be cyclic of order $p$; hence, since $1_R\neq 0$, $1$ will generate the ring additively. So every element of the ring is of the form $n\cdot 1_R$, with $0\leq n\lt p$. Show this determines the multiplication and that your ring must in fact be $\mathbb{F}_p$, the field with $p$ elements.

Comment: For the multiplication, are you trying to show that every element has a multiplicative inverse?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $a\in R$ and the map $\mu : x \mapsto ax$. This is an endomorphism of the additive group of $R$. If $a\ne0$, the image of $\mu$ is not $0$ because $\mu(1)=a$. Since $R$ has $p$ elements, the image must be the whole of $R$. In particular, there is $b$ such that $ab=1$ and $R$ is a field. Alternatively, the kernel must be $0$ and $R$ is a domain.

Answer (score 0):

The surjective ringhomomorphism $\mathbb Z \rightarrow R$, $1\mapsto 1_R$ must have non-trivial Kernel $n\mathbb Z $, such that $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z = R$ has $p$ elements. Therefore $n=p$ and $R=\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z=\mathbb F_p$

Comment: The OP might have trouble showing that this homomorphism is surjective.

Comment: If $R$ has order $p$, then $\Bbb F_p \to R$ is a well-defined ring homomorphism, and since $\Bbb F_p$ is a field, it is injective. Then it must be also surjective (hence an isomorphism) by equality of cardinalities.