# There are only two non isomorphic rings with $p$ elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-rings

> Prove that for any prime $p$ there are only two non isomorphic rings with $p$ elements.

I have found out there are up to two rings of order p , they are $\mathbb Z_p$ and $\mathbb C_p$.
Please help in doing the proof!!

Comment: What do you mean by $C_p$ ?

Comment: what is $\mathbb C_p$..??

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043373/any-ring-of-prime-order-commutative

Comment: Cyclic additive groups  is $C_p$

Comment: what is the relation between the link

Comment: The answer to the link is just what you are looking for.

Comment: it was proved that there are exactly two distinct ring structure over the group $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: Therefore $C_p=\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ !

Comment: @RossMillikan But how to show that $R\cong (\Bbb Z_p,+,×)$ if $R$ does not have a unit element, i.e $1\neq 0,$ where $×$ is such an operation so that $a.b=0,\forall a,b\in \Bbb Z_p$ ?

Answer (score 4):

By $\mathbb{C}_p$ you mean the zero ring, right?

In fact, if $R$ is a non-zero ring of order $p$, let $a \in R$ such that $a R \ne \{ 0 \}$.

The function $R \to R$ given by $x \mapsto a x$ is a group homomorphism. Looking at the kernel, one sees that it has to be injective, thus bijective. In particular there is an element $e$ such that $a e = a$. Since $a \ne 0$, we have $a a \ne a 0 = 0$, so also $R a \ne \{ 0 \}$, and the map $R \to R$ given by $x \mapsto x a$ is bijective. So there is $f$ such that $f a = a$. Now it is easy to see that $f$ is a left unit, and $e$ is a right unit. So $e = f e = e$ is the unit, and the rest is not difficult.

Please try and fill up the details.

---

**PS** The answer in the posted link is definitely sleeker.

Comment: how can zero ring have p elements??

Comment: @AnkitGhosh: *"zero ring"* means $ab = 0, \forall a, b.$ it's different from the *trivial ring* $\{0 \}$

Comment: ok I have understood it.... thank you